# How to understand DiracComb[t/T]

Tags: functions

From *Mathematica* Reference, `DiracComb[t/T]` should equal to

```
Assuming[T > 0,
  Simplify[Sum[DiracDelta[t/T - n], {n, -∞, ∞}]]]
(* DiracComb[t/T] *)
```

But why `DiracComb[t/T]` also equal to

```
Assuming[T > 0,
  Simplify[T*Sum[DiracDelta[t - n*T], {n, -∞, ∞}]]]
(* DiracComb[t/T] *)
```

it seems that `DiracDelta[t]` equals `T*DiracDelta[t/T]`? could anyone explain this, thank you!

My question comes from that: the `FourierTransform` of `f[t]` is not exatly equals what I expected!

```
f[t_] := Sum[DiracDelta[t - n*T], {n, -∞, ∞}]
FourierTransform[f[t], t, ω, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
(* DiracComb[(T ω)/(2 π)] *)
```

what I expected is `F[ω]`

```
F[ω_] = (2*π)/T*Sum[DiracDelta[ω - n*(2 π)/T], {n, -∞, ∞}]
(* (Abs[T] DiracComb[(T ω)/(2 π)])/T *)
```

But after evaluated, they are same!

Comment: $\delta(t)=T\delta(t/T)$ is a [basic scaling property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry) of the Dirac $\delta$-function.